# How do I import serialized items through the Sitecore API during package installation?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I'm trying to import serialized items through the API of Sitecore during installation of a package.

I've modified the serialization config in App_Config to the path that I have the serialized items(which is inside the website in a sub folder). When I run the installer (with a debugger attached), I don't see any errors. The data is not imported on the first run, but is on the second one.

I found inspiratiaon in the `/sitecore/admin/serialization.aspx` page which does the same thing. If I run import on master on that page it works on the first try. I must be missing some little parameter, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what's wrong.
Here's the code I have:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    var options = new LoadOptions(Factory.GetDatabase("master"));
    options.ForceUpdate = true;
    options.DisableEvents = true;
    Manager.LoadTree(Path.Combine(PathUtils.Root, "master"),options);
}
```

Is there something that stands out which I may be missing or that could help me move in the right direction?

Comment: I will have you know that the reason this is failing is because I am copying serialization.config into App_Config/Include before doing the serialization. And that is why it works on the second try (the config is allready there). I tried extracting the code that gets the path which works. However the list of paths to include in the config file is now missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to deserialize items during package installation? Did you have a chance to take a look at Courier? http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Courier.aspx

It will turn the serialized items into the package for you, it can also be used during the build, from command line.